# Swift delegate protocol not updating with locationManager

Tags: ios, swift

I have 2 views which the `childView` communicates with the `parentView`. I am using `Google maps SDK` to track a users location however if I `startUpdatingLocation()` using a button, the protocol does not work however if I initiate `startUpdatingLocation()` as soon as the app loads it works fine. Below are my `Two controller` files.

I am simply trying to display the location in a label but not sure why the protocol is not working after button click.

Child:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

protocol LocationUpdateDelegate{
func delegateUserLocation(mapChildController:MapChildController, userLocation: String)
}

class MapChildController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate
{

@IBOutlet weak var mapView: GMSMapView!
let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
var didFindMyLocation = false
var myLocations:[String] = []
var alreadyUpdatedLocation = false
var locationDelegate:LocationUpdateDelegate?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    var camera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithLatitude(-33.86, longitude: 151.20, zoom: 15, bearing: 0, viewingAngle: 45)
    var mapView = GMSMapView.mapWithFrame(CGRectZero, camera: camera)

    mapView.myLocationEnabled = true
    self.view = mapView

    if NSProcessInfo().isOperatingSystemAtLeastVersion(NSOperatingSystemVersion(majorVersion: 8, minorVersion: 0, patchVersion: 0)) {
        println("iOS >= 8.0.0")
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    }

    mapView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "myLocation", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.New, context: nil)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String, ofObject object: AnyObject, change: [NSObject : AnyObject], context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
    if !didFindMyLocation {
        let myLocation: CLLocation = change[NSKeyValueChangeNewKey] as! CLLocation
        var mapView = self.view as! GMSMapView
        mapView.camera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithTarget(myLocation.coordinate, zoom: 15.0)
        mapView.settings.myLocationButton = true
        didFindMyLocation = true
    }
}

func locationManager(manager:CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations:[AnyObject]) {
    var locValue:CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location.coordinate

    myLocations.append("\(locValue.latitude)/\(locValue.longitude)")
    self.locationDelegate?.delegateUserLocation(self, userLocation: "From child")
    println("Child location: \(locValue.latitude)/\(locValue.longitude)")
}

func trackingToggle()
{
    if !alreadyUpdatedLocation
    {
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

        println("Tracking started")
        alreadyUpdatedLocation = true
    }
    else
    {
        locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()

        println("Tracking stopped")
        alreadyUpdatedLocation = false
    }
}
}
```

Parent:

```
import UIKit

struct Constants {
static let embedSegue = "embedSegue"
}

class MapMainController: UIViewController, LocationUpdateDelegate
{
let mapChild = MapChildController()
var alreadyUpdatedLocation = false;
@IBOutlet weak var startTrackingButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var MapStatsView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var txtUserLocation: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == Constants.embedSegue {
        let mapChildController = segue.destinationViewController as! MapChildController
        mapChildController.locationDelegate = self
    }
}

func delegateUserLocation(mapChildController: MapChildController, userLocation: String) {
    println("Parent location: \(userLocation)");
    txtUserLocation.text = userLocation
}

@IBAction func startTrackingTapped(sender: UIButton) {
    mapChild.trackingToggle();

    if !alreadyUpdatedLocation
    {
        alreadyUpdatedLocation = true
        startTrackingButton.setTitle("Stop Tracking", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    }
    else
    {
        alreadyUpdatedLocation = false
        startTrackingButton.setTitle("Start Tracking", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the `mapChildController` to self just before you segue to another view:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == Constants.embedSegue {
        let mapChildController = segue.destinationViewController as! MapChildController
        mapChildController.locationDelegate = self
```

After you just set the `delegate` to self your `viewController` went out of scope, now your `delegate` is nil again and will never be called.
You need to set the `delegate` in `viewDidLoad`

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you mean. The prepareForSegue actually works if I call locationManager.startUpdatingLocation() in viewDidLoad.

It doesn't work if I call locationManager.startUpdatingLocation() in trackingToggle method